# Jquery only select one li

Tags: jquery

I tried to write the value of a li- tag to an input, my problem is that it only add oneli. How can i achive that several values of the li- are added seperated by commas! And also it would be good when each li-  value can be added only once! Thanks, and sorry that i have absolutly no knowledge!

http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<input type="text" id="meinOutput"/>


$("li").click(function() {
var selects = $("li").html();
$("#meinOutput").val(selects);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new values and commas to the inputs value like so:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var sel = $(this).text();

    $("#meinOutput").val(function(i, v) { 
        var p = v.length ? v.split(','):[];

        if( $.inArray(sel, p) == -1 ) 
            p.push(sel);
        return p.join(',');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/10/)

Comment: Glad too see *someone* reading the question. Though this doesn't solve the *"And also it would be good when each li- value can be added only once!"* part ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - Yup, for once I got it! Should be an easier way to do this with join() ?

Comment: and how can i define that each li (value) can only added once?

Comment: @EmSta: Depends on what should happen when a `li` is clicked a second time. Do you want to append the value (and remove it from its previous position) or just do nothing?

Comment: Do nothing! Thanks for your help! And very intresting website @FelixKling!

Comment: I would +1 once more if I could. You can make it even nicer (IMO) by passing a callback to `.val`: `$("#meinOutput").val(function(i, v) {  var p = v.split(','); if( ... ){ p.push(sel); v = p.join(','); }; return v; });`

Comment: @FelixKling - good idea, having some issues with split creating an array with an empty string as the first index when there's no value, so either have to filter or use a ternary to make sure the array is empty ?

Comment: Sorry but for me i doesnt work, dont know what mistake i made! http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/8/ @adeneo

Comment: @EmSta: You didn't, `.push` doesn't return an array (unfortunately in this case). You have to do it in two lines: `val.push(sel); $("#meinOutput").val( val.join(', ') );`, but now the answer changed anyway ;)

Comment: @EmSta - my bad, was chaining a bit too much, and push can't be chained with a join.

Answer (score 3):

try `var selects = $(this).html();` that should do the job

reson for that is that `$('li')` will return all objects that fit the selector and therefore the `html()` will only access the first element of that list. `this` is in the contect of the method a reference to exactly that element that the click happend to.

http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/5/

if you want to append you have to use

`var selects = $("#meinOutput").val() + $(this).html();`

furthermore if you want to have the items comma seperated you should check if val is empty and if not append the new html with a comma:

```
var old = $("#meinOutput").val();
var selects = old == "" ? $(this).html() : old + "; " + $(this).html();`
```

for the sake of allowing every value only once there are various approaches. for example you could create an array in which you insert the lis you already added to the text and check if they were added if a new one was pressed - or if the content of the lis is unique you can just check if the content already is present in the  output.

Comment: now each time it simply replaces the old value of the input but i want that it adds the new value!

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: would you want one of the last two options to be explained more detailed?

Comment: There is one down-side to using `.html()` though, as I commented in my answer. See the blunder [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/12/)

Comment: thats true, i don´t know enough about the contents of the li, as said before, unique content? html formatted content?

Answer (score 3):

Here is crude, but working solution.

First I check to see if it is the first entry being made. If yes, there is no `,` at the front. If not, then we append `,` + `value of clicked item`.

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory, so I'll include it here. In case you want to see it in action, here is a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/11/)**

HTML

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="Output"/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(e){
        var sel = $(this).html();
        if($("#Output").val().length==0)
        {
           $("#Output").val(sel);
        }
        else
        {
           $("#Output").val($("#Output").val() + ", " + sel);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS (Okay! Granted it is not necessary, but I kind of love the hand :) )

```
li:hover
{
cursor:hand;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Hope this was of some use.

Comment: There is one down-side to using `.html()` though. See the blunder [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QNtbp/12/)

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).html()` or `this.innerHTML` instead of `$("li").html()` which will select all the li's and give yout the html of the first one in the collection. *Ok i missed out the duplicate part so editing the answer*:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var selected = this.innerHTML;
    $("#meinOutput").val(function(_, curText){
        var ct = !curText.length ? [] : curText.split(';');
        if($.inArray(selected, ct) > -1) return curText;
        ct.push(selected);
        return ct.join(';');
    }); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj86b/)**

Comment: now each time it simply replaces the old value of the input but i want that it adds the new value!

Comment: @EmSta i missed out the add only once part.. So just updated it. But looks liek you already got one from adeneo...